# How to add data-valid='parsley' as a form attribute in django crispy form for client-side validation?

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms, parsley

I am a beginner in django crispy form, i want to make my form tag as

```
<form data-parsley-validate>
    {{ form.as_p }}
</form>
```

I want to know how to pass data_validate = 'parsley' in to the html page having the crispy form tag from the form.py?

Answer (score 0):

The docs on [custom helper attributes](http://django-crispy-forms.readthedocs.org/en/latest/form_helper.html#custom-helper-attributes) suggest you should be able to set `attrs` on your form helper:

```
self.helper.attrs = {'data-parsley-validate': 1}
```

This will render the form tag

```
<form data-parsley-validate="1">
```

instead of

```
<form data-parsley-validate>
```

as you want. However it might be good enough to get parsley to work.